# Finding a minimal graph cover over a tree

Tags: graph-theory, optimization, symbolic-computation

I have a directed rooted tree with $n$ nodes.

Every node $n$ in the tree has a type $t_n$ and a cost $c_n$.

I also have a set of allowed node contractions in the tree.

I would like to find the minimal total cost of the tree when applying the node contractions.

Example problem:
Tree:
[image]

costs:
$$c_0=1$$
$$c_1=2$$
$$c_3=4$$
$$c_4=2$$
$$c_5=2$$
$$c_6=2$$
$$c_2=5$$

Contraction subsets on the form {nodetypes, newcost}->newtype:
$\{3,4, 1\}\to7, \{5,6, 1\}\to8, \{5,2, 3\}\to9$

So a solution would be to contract 5 & 6 to a new node for lower cost. But it is also possible to contract 5 & 2 for a lower cost and contracting 3 & 4.

Is there any known algorithm or research I could use for this problem to find a minimal total cost for the tree?

This is intended to be used for simplifying algebraic expressions in a custom made algebra.

Comment: Minimum spanning tree?

Comment: Doesn't really do node contractions unless I'm missing something? I also already have a tree

Comment: Can a node that is the result of a contraction be further contracted or not?

Comment: @Anis Yes it can

Comment: So how does the possible contraction list express that? What is the identifier of a node contraction? Can you give such an example?

Comment: @Anis A contraction matches some kind of pattern of nodes for example a type 2 being the parent of a type 4 and a type 5 and replaces that with a type 8. The type 8 might be part of the pattern of other contractions

Comment: OK, and if I understand correctly, {5,2, 3}->9 would replace 2 by 9, while {5,6, 1}->8 would create another node 8, that is a child of 2?

Comment: @Anis yes, also in {5,2, 3}->9 then 6 would be a child of 9

Comment: Okay last question, the number of children can be 0, 1, or 2 but no more? and we can only contract two nodes if they are siblings or parent/child?

Comment: @Anis The number of children can be arbitrarily large, contractions will be either connected or siblings but can be arbitrarily large (but it is unlikely that larger than 3 will occur for me in the near future)

Comment: I don't know if there is a specific algorithm for what you ask, but from what I understand, this could be approached using a backtracking approach, which would give an optimal solution. There is probably no out of the box solution, and you would have to implement the solver yourself.

Comment: @Anis Yes, I was hoping for a mapping to a known problem which would have made it much easier